# How to SSH into compute-engine?

Tags: google-compute-engine

Coming from AWS to Google Compute Engine, I find it very confusing through how many hoops I have to jump to get a simple SSH working.

I have added my public key
`cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`

[image]

but I still can't ssh into it.  Is there any other step or firewall settings I have to enable first?

Comment: Have you explored this documentation: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/connecting-to-instance. You might try to use Cloud SDK "gcloud compute ssh" command to do this.

Comment: Thanks, I managed to make it happen after installing `gcloud` like this: `gcloud compute --project "project-name" ssh --zone "us-east1-c" "server-vpn-1"`  But I can't figure out how to do SCP via gcloud.  Very frustrating.

Comment: You can also use the CLI command $ gcloud compute ssh from Cloud Shell https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/starting-cloud-shell
This will ensure that you run the latest Cloud SDK version.

Just in case this might be helpful I'm leaving here a guide to troubleshoot SSH in GCE https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-ssh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like `gcloud compute ssh` there is also a [`gcloud compute scp`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/scp) command.

Both of these commands are just adding the key to the project-wide metadata (which is downloaded by a daemon running on your instances) and then call ssh or scp.  The keys that gcloud generate are stored in `~/.ssh/google_compute_engine`, so you can directly use scp or ssh if you want like:

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/google_compute_engine houmie@INSTANCE_IP
```